# how to apply a matrix transform to entire svg's paths not just one path?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, snap.svg

Anyone has any idea why when I use the code below to apply a matrix to an svg's entire paths there are some issues like the svg being cut or  jumping when the settimeout function is finished? :

```
  var matrix = g.transform().localMatrix;
  var mySet = g.selectAll('path');
  mySet.forEach( function( el ) {
  var newPathString = Snap.path.map( el, matrix ).toString();
  el.attr({ d: newPathString });
  } );

 var svg = g.select('svg');
 var newObj = svg.clone();
 s.g( newObj );
 g.remove();
 setTimeout(function(){alert(newObj.toString())},8000); 

 }, 7000 );
 } );
```

edit: what I want to achieve is to get the svg's paths markup with matrix transformation applied to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting all your `path` tags inot a `g` tag and applying transformations to that `g` tag.

Comment: thanks Vlas, I am loading an svg file and trying to get all the paths from that svg file. what would you suggest in that case to get the entie paths from an svg file?

Comment: Reparent the paths using appendChild.

Comment: Robert, Actually I used this:  el.attr({ d: newPathString }).appendChild(); but it does make the code stop working from there I guess. I guess because the 'appendChild is a DOM method (not a Snap method)'.